# Flutter TextFormField validation with Firestore

Tags: flutter, validation, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a TextFormField and I want to validate it. With the validation, I want to get data from Firestore and that if the input value in the TextFormField exists in the Firestore database, it should return "Exists", else return null. I don't know if I'm doing the right thing but after in input the value and even if the value exists it doesn't return anything. Please help

```
class GenerateUID extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idAreadyExistsString;
  final String noSPacesAllowedString;
  final String fieldCannotBeEmptyString;
  const GenerateUID(
      {super.key,
      required this.idAreadyExistsString,
      required this.noSPacesAllowedString,
      required this.fieldCannotBeEmptyString});

  @override
  State<GenerateUID> createState() => _GenerateUIDState();
}

class _GenerateUIDState extends State<GenerateUID> {
  TextEditingController employeeIDController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: TextFormField(
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9]")),
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
          ],
          controller: employeeIDController,
          style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          onChanged: (value) {
            _formkey.currentState?.validate();
          },
          validator: (value) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("ADMIN IDS")
                .where("ID", isEqualTo: value)
                .get()
                .then((valuess) {
              if (valuess.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                return widget.idAreadyExistsString;
              }
            });

            if (value!.contains(" ")) {
              return (widget.noSPacesAllowedString);
            }

            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return (widget.fieldCannotBeEmptyString);
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: does your call to firebase successfully  got data if you entered a correct id? try to print valuess

Comment: Well, no. That's why I wrote here for help

Comment: So, you should get the whole ids a List<Id> before even user get write a TF, then in validation check whether the input is contained in that list. got me! that's because you can't mark the validator as an async function you should await for get Method. so get data at the launch

Comment: Would you mind helping with this? I would be very grateful

Comment: it's ok, just edit your ques and share the whole widget, is it stateless or ful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, i was on hurry.
I have explained my solution in pseudo code, you need to write your code based on the idea.

here

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{

List<String> ids = [];

  MyApp({super.key});

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    initiateIdsList();

  }

  void initiateIdsList()async{
// initialize your list here, refactor the following pseudo code
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("ADMIN IDS").get().then((v){
                  v.forEach(e){
                    ids.add(e);
                  }
                });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    YourTFF(
      validator: (value){

        if (value!.contains(" ")) {
              return (widget.noSPacesAllowedString);
            }

            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return (widget.fieldCannotBeEmptyString);
            }
            if(ids.contains(value)){
              print('already exist');
            }
            return null;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

This is because we can't mark the validator callback as an asynchronous function.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @EbenOasis u r wlcm